# Decibinary for xth number (Python code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, number-systems

I created the code for the problem description below. It works for \$N\le10^6\$ but after that it gives a time out error. What I don't understand is how to optimize the code using dynamic programming. I have used a dictionary to create decibinary numbers with the formula mentioned in [this OEIS post](https://oeis.org/A028897). for more description link: [Hackerrank decibinary problem forum](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/decibinary-numbers/forum)

> **Problem description:**
>
> Let's combine decimal and binary numbers in a new system we call
> decibinary! In this number system, each digit ranges from 0 to 9 (like
> the decimal number system), but the place value of each digit
> corresponds to the one in the binary number system. For example, the
> decibinary number 2016 represents the decimal number 24 because:
>
> \$ (2016)_{decibinary}= 2\cdot2^3+0\cdot2^2+1\cdot2^1+6\cdot2^0 = (24)_{10} \$
>
> Pretty cool system, right? Unfortunately, there's a problem: two
> different decibinary numbers can evaluate to the same decimal value!
> For example, the decibinary number 2008 also evaluates to the decimal
> value 24:
>
> \$ (2008)_{decibinary}= 2\cdot2^3+0\cdot2^2+0\cdot2^1+8\cdot2^0  = (24)_{10}\$
>
> This is a major problem because our new number system has no real
> applications beyond this challenge!
>
> Consider an infinite list of non-negative decibinary numbers that is
> sorted according to the following rules:
>
> - The decibinary numbers are sorted in increasing order of the decimal value that they evaluate to.
> - Any two decibinary numbers that evaluate to the same decimal value are ordered by increasing decimal value, meaning the equivalent
>   decibinary values are strictly interpreted and compared as decimal
>   values and the smaller decimal value is ordered first.
>
> You will be given q queries in the form of an integer, q. For each x,
> find and print the \$x^{\textrm{th}}\$  decibinary number in the list on a new
> line.
>
> [image]
>
> **Function Description**
>
> Complete the decibinaryNumbers function in the editor below. For each
> query, it should return the decibinary number at that one-based index.
>
> decibinaryNumbers has the following parameter(s):
>
> x: the index of the decibinary number to return
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains an integer, \$q\$, the number of queries. Each of
> the next \$q\$ lines contains an integer, \$x\$, describing a query.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> \$ 1 \le q \le 10^5 \$
>
> \$ 1 \le x \le 10^{16} \$
>
> **Output Format**
>
> For each query, print a single integer denoting the the xth decibinary
> number in the list. Note that this must be the actual decibinary
> number and not its decimal value. Use 1-based indexing.
>
> **Sample Input 0**
>
> ```
> 5
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 10
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 0**
>
> ```
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 10
> 100
> ```
>
> *Additional samples omitted…*

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
from math import floor
from collections import defaultdict

a={0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3}

for i in range(4,10**6):
    a[i]=2*a[floor(i/10)]+i%10

d=defaultdict(lambda:[])
i=1
x_to_decibin={}
for x,y in a.items():
    d[y].append(x)

i=1
l=list(d.values())
l=sum(l,[])

ind=[i for i in range(1,len(l)+1)]
x_to_decibin=dict(zip(ind,l))
print(x_to_decibin)
    
def decibinaryNumbers(x):
    return x_to_decibin[x]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    q = int(input().strip())

    for q_itr in range(q):
        x = int(input().strip())

        result = decibinaryNumbers(x)

        fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

First there's some script cleanups I want to mention.

```py
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
from math import floor
from collections import defaultdict
```

I'll assume that the imports from the default input may be needed, but I think it's pretty unnecessary to import floor in addition to math. Usually `math.floor` is short enough, but it's also not needed in this case.

```py
a={0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3}

for i in range(4,10**6):
    a[i]=2*a[floor(i/10)]+i%10
```

Instead of using floor here, you can use a double division operator which will also do floored division. You also don't need a `dict` for this purpose, and could instead just initialize a list to the size you need.

```py
N = 10**6+1 # Max size to compute (plus one for offset)

a = [0]*N

for i in range(1,N):
    a[i]=2*a[i//10]+i%10
```

---

```py
d=defaultdict(lambda:[])
i=1
x_to_decibin={}
for x,y in a.items():
    d[y].append(x)

i=1
l=list(d.values())
l=sum(l,[])
```

The `i=1` statements don't do anything here since `i` is overwritten when next used. `x_to_decibin` is also set later. The intermediate list is also unneeded since `dict_values` is iterable.

```py
d=defaultdict(lambda:[])
# Iterate through decibin values (index) and add them to a list of their decimal value (element)
for index, element in enumerate(a):
    d[element].append(index)

l=sum(d.values(),[])
```

---

```py
ind=[i for i in range(1,len(l)+1)]
x_to_decibin=dict(zip(ind,l))
print(x_to_decibin)

def decibinaryNumbers(x):
    return x_to_decibin[x]
```

I'm not sure if you included the print in a submission, but printing a fairly large structure won't be great. `x_to_decibin` also doesn't need to be created at all since you can just use `l` directly with a simple 1 offset.

```py
def decibinaryNumbers(x):
    return l[x - 1] # Get value from precomputed list (with 1 offset)
```

With all of these changes, the running time for the setup with `N=10**6+1` on my machine went from 5.7 to 2.4 seconds. From here, profiling shows that by far the slowest part of the script is calling `sum` on the large iterable. Replacing it with a `itertools.chain.from_iterable` call sped it up to 0.15 seconds.

However, I am only able to increase N to about `10**8` before memory starts becoming an issue. These changes allow for doing subtask 3 of `10**7` pretty quickly, but precomputing every value is just not going to work for the full size. If you want to do that, you'll instead need something that generates a value at runtime. You'll have to change your method to do this though. Try following some of what people have put in the discussions.

Final code:

```py
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

N = 10**6+1

a = [0]*N

for i in range(1,N):
    a[i]=2*a[i//10]+i%10

d=defaultdict(lambda:[])
for index, element in enumerate(a):
    d[element].append(index)

l=tuple(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))

def decibinaryNumbers(x):
    return l[x - 1]
```

Comment: I didn't understand what they did in the discussion section. I only want to optimize this code. Anything above 10^6 gives me memory error.

Comment: Running it for 10^7 only used about 830MB on my machine, so I'd be a bit surprised to see a `MemoryError` there. You could try using `del` statements to delete `a` and `d` once done with them, and also using `array.array('L')` from the `array` module instead of the current itereables for `a`, `l`, and and the `defaultdict` lambda.